How can I activate HTTPS on specific pages of my website
I have a multivendor ecommerce store (using the Dokan plugin) and having problems with product uploads from vendors. It doesn't allow vendors to attach files, product images banners
my website already has an SSL certificate and I have activated the force HTTPS on my account pages., now I need to force HTTPS on the vendor dashboard for them to be able to upload products on their end on the frontend of the website
